# Javascript / jQuery Find & Replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, find

I would like to find:

`<input type="button" class=" btn btn-lg btn-info" value="Continue" onclick="loadFinal();">`

and replace it with:

`<input type="button" class=" btn btn-lg btn-info" value="Continue" onclick="loadFinal(); applyCode();">`.

In short, insert `applyCode();` to `onclick`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things you can do. Approach 1 would remove all click events from the button and add events, approach 2 would add additional events in addition to the existing event.

**Approach 1**

```
$('input:button').unbind('click'); // remove all click events associated
$('input:button').on("click",function() // add new click events
{
  loadFinal();
applyCode();
});
```

**Approach 2**

```
$('input:button').on("click",function() // add additional click events
    {
    applyCode();
    });
```

**UPDATE :**

In order to apply or append the applycode() event to the same element that has loadfinal(), you can use `$._data` to extract the events and check if a certain event exists or not.

```
$("input:button").click(function() {
    var events = $._data(document.getElementById('btn1'), "events");
    $.each(events,function(i,o)
    {
        alert(i);// give the event type like 'click'
        alert(o); // give the event object - you can extract the event name from the object and do the compare with the existint event.
    });
});
```

Alternately, you can directly target the click event.

```
var events = $._data(document.getElementById('btn1'), "events").click;
        $.each(events,function(i,o)
        {
            alert(i);// give the index 
            alert(o); // give the event object - you can extract the event name from the object and do the compare with the existint event.
        });
    });
```

Implementation : http://jsfiddle.net/qk5qj33u/15/

Comment: These solutions works! Thanks. But as mentioned on the post beneath, I would need an ID or some way targeting that input only, since that is not the only input tag on the document. Could it be targeted by using load final(); since it's unique on the document.

Comment: I've updated the solution. Please follow the section marked with UPDATE.

Comment: I see you are getting the element by ID, "btn1". But, I can't add that ID to the form. I don't have access to the source code. Can this be done using get Element By the onclick value?

Comment: Unfortunately that's the only native solution that works with jquery 1.10+. If that doesn't workout for you, you may wanna look into other API's such as http://github.com/sebastien-p/jquery.hasEventListener

Comment: OK. Understood. I used instead the Approach 2 of your first solution. Which in turn applies: applyCode(); to all <input>, which is ok. Thanks! Right?

Comment: The answer from Rory McCrossan below also worked for me.

Comment: Yup. Approach 2 would add applyCode() function to all input type button

Answer (score 0):

I don't think find & replace is what you'd be best using. Instead you can use Javascript to attach events for you. As you've tagged the question with jQuery, try this:

```
<input type="button" class=" btn btn-lg btn-info" value="Continue">
```

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type=button]').click(function() {
        loadFinal();
        applyCode();
    });
});
```

Note that the above selector is purely for demonstration purposes, you'd be better setting an `id` attribute, or single specific `class` on the element and selecting it by that instead. You could even hook to the `submit` event of the form, assuming this button is used for that purpose.

Comment: This solution works! Thanks! But, as you mention, it needs an ID. I can't add an ID because the code is already given and can't be modified. Is there a way to get element by attribute? the value loadFina(); is unique on the whole document.

Comment: OK. Understood. I deleted from your code: load final();, which in turn applies: applyCode(); to all <input>, which is ok. Thanks! Right?